# Django cant find static files 404error

Tags: python, django

I'm using django to create apps in the project.
I'm going to make common files into templates and static folders under the project folder of the project. However, when the server is running, the files in the templates are found well, but the files in the static folder are not imported.
I tried a few attempts through a search, but it didn't work, so I ask questions. I would appreciate an answer.

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

my folder structure

```
project
-app1
-app2
-templates
  -app1
    -index.html
  -app2
    -index.html
-static
  -style.css
  -app.js
```

html code

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in settings.py.

Instead of:

```
STATIC_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
```

Write this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got `django.contrib.staticfiles` included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/